# Thinking Sphinx and Norwegian characters (æ, ø, å)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I've set up Thinking Sphinx for wildcard searches, but I'm having trouble searching for words containing Norwegian characters, as the automatic starring seems to mess up the query. For instance, my search for "ål" will end up with:

```
  Sphinx Query (2.8ms)  å*l*
  Sphinx  Found 0 results
```

If I manually enter the stars in the search term, "*ål*", the expected results are returned:

```
  Sphinx Query (3.7ms)  *ål*
  Sphinx  Found 8 results
```

It seems somehow the å (as well as æ, ø) gets misinterpreted when automatically adding the stars.

Anyone here familiar with this problem?

---

My config/sphinx.yml looks as follows:

```
development:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 2
  charset_table: "U+FF10..U+FF19->0..9, U+FF21..U+FF3A->a..z, U+FF41..U+FF5A->a..z, 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z,
                  U+C5->U+E5, U+E5, U+D8->U+F8, U+F8, U+C6->U+E6, U+E6,
                  U+C4->U+E4, U+E4, U+D6->U+F6, U+F6"
```

And a couple of examples of searches performed in the console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :014 > ThinkingSphinx.search("ål", :star => true).count
 => 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :015 > ThinkingSphinx.search("*ål*", :star => true).count
 => 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in recent commits - for the moment, you'll need to grab it via the repo:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx',
 :git => 'git://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx.git'
```